# Using try and except in a list

Tags: python

I´m a beginner with Python and I´m trying to create a list of 5 items. Then i want to ask the user to add one more item and decide where in the list he/she wants it to be located. After that i print the list with the new item. I have managed to do it till here, but the problem is when i want to use the except format if the user introduces a location that is not in the list (for example 6, since there are only 5 items on the list). It doesn´t work. Any help would be higly appreciated! Here is what i´ve got so far:

```
collection = ["plate", "fork", "knife", "spoon", "cup"]
    try:
      location = input("Where do you want to insert the new item?: ")
      location = int(location)
      newitem = input("Which item do you want to add to the list?: ")
      if location <5:
         collection.insert(location,newitem)
   except IndexError:
         print("Wrong index used in accessing list. Please add a valid index")
   print (collection)
```

Comment: There can't be any `IndexError` as you explicitely only insert if the index is valid. Either use `if / else` or don't check with your `if` and use `try / except`.

Answer (score 1):

First, here is a correctly indented version of your code:

```
collection = ["plate", "fork", "knife", "spoon", "cup"]
try:
    location = input("Where do you want to insert the new item?: ")
    location = int(location)
    newitem = input("Which item do you want to add to the list?: ")
    if location <5:
        collection.insert(location, newitem)
except IndexError:
    print("Wrong index used in accessing list. Please add a valid index")
print (collection)
```

Second, the `if` statement checks that the insertion cannot happen if you're too far. So you should not expect anything to happen unless your remove it.

**But even if you do**, `list.insert` **will never throw an IndexError**, it will just insert in the last spot (actually it inserts at the first available spot before the requested index). So you cannot use `try`/`except` here:

```
l = [1,2,3]
l.insert(1000, 4)
l
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use try/except and force the user to input a reasonable location, you could generalize it by using `len(collection)` and use `AssertionError` instead.

```
collection = ["plate", "fork", "knife", "spoon", "cup"]
try:
  location = input("Where do you want to insert the new item?: ")
  location = int(location)
  newitem = input("Which item do you want to add to the list?: ")
  assert location <= len(collection)
  collection.insert(location,newitem)
except AssertionError:
  print("Wrong index used in accessing list. Please add a valid index")
print (collection)
```

`assert` raises an exception when the condition is False. You can add an informative string to the assert also, as

```
assert location <= len(collection), 'Wrong index used.'
```

This causes the `AssertionError` exception to be raised with the message `Wrong index used.` to be printed. This would typically be done if the exception were not handled, though, and the program would terminate.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes:

- Add a while loop to keep asking the user when the input is incorrect
- Always check the length of the collection by using len()

```py
 collection = ["plate", "fork", "knife", "spoon", "cup"]
        while True:
          location = input("Where do you want to insert the new item?: ")
          location = int(location)
          newitem = input("Which item do you want to add to the list?: ")
          if location < len(collection):
             collection.insert(location, newitem)
             break
          else:
             print("Wrong index used in accessing list. Please add a valid index")
       print (collection)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it i hope it help you

```
collection = ["plate", "fork", "knife", "spoon", "cup"]
try:
    location = input("Where do you want to insert the new item?: ")
    location = int(location)
    newitem = input("Which item do you want to add to the list?: ")
    if location < len(collection):
        collection.insert(location, newitem)
    else:
        print("Wrong index used in accessing list. Please add a valid index")
print(collection)
```